# Is there a Stan Lee reference in WandaVision?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, stan-lee, wandavision

I know that Stan Lee's final cameo was in *Avengers: Endgame*. However, I would assume that the MCU is still going to honour him in some way: whether it be some clear cut reference or something a little more minor.

Was there a reference to Stan Lee in *WandaVision*?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

The one possible reference that I noticed (and also found to be referenced on the internet) about Stan Lee was in *Episode 7: Breaking the fourth Wall*.

In the episode’s opening theme, a license plate is shown (*image below*) with a six-digit number on top **122822**. This is possibly a nod to Stan Lee's birthday which is on December 28th, 1922 (written **12/28/1922** in the US).

[image: WandaVision license plate]
 <sub>*Opening scene from Wadavision Episode 7: Breaking the fourth Wall (click to enlarge)*</sub>

In an [interview](https://www.ign.com/articles/wandavision-stan-lee-easter-egg-confirmed) with ScreenRant, WandaVision director Matt Shakman has confirmed this Easter Egg dedicated to Stan Lee.

Comment: It would be an unbelievable coincidence if that weren't deliberate.

Answer (score 28):

The director for *WandaVision*, Matt Shakman, said in an interview for ScreenRant that there is at least one reference to Stan Lee: a license plate.

> Matt Shakman: I mean, there certainly are some that folks have noticed that are important. A certain license plate, perhaps, in an opening title recently. We have to honor Stan Lee, of course.
>
> But we were very careful about the breadcrumbs that we left, because it is a mystery and a puzzle box. You want to make sure that all the pieces of evidence add up. And then there are fun little easter eggs on the side - many of which people have found already, if not all of them, and then analyzed. We were trying to build this story, and make sure that we were putting out all the little pieces that would eventually add up to complete the puzzle.
>
> <sub>[ScreenRant, WandaVision's Stan Lee Easter Egg Confirmed](https://screenrant.com/wandavision-stan-lee-easter-egg-liscense-plate-confirmed/)</sub>

Here, he is referring to the license plate we see on one of the cars in the opening credits to episode 7, "Breaking the Fourth Wall". The license plate reads "WANDA" with the number "122822" above it. This is referring to Stan Lee's date of birth which is 28th December 1922 or 12/28/[19]22 (MM/dd/[yy]yy).

[image: The license plate]

In the following episode, "Previously On...", we have another reference to Lee. During the flashbacks to Wanda's past we witness her drive from S.W.O.R.D. to Westview and the license plate for her car. Under the normal details the word "EXCELSIOR" is written which is clearly referencing Stan Lee's motto and sign off.

[image: A yellow box highlights the license plate on Wanda's car]
<sub>[*Image taken from this ScreenRant article.*](https://screenrant.com/wandavision-episode-8-stan-lee-excelsior-easter-egg/)</sub>

Comment: Excelsior is the NY state motto and standardly available on plates (https://dmv.ny.gov/plates/excelsior-plates), so that's not obviously a deliberate reference. On the other hand, the Excelsior plates are new and so fitting I can't imagine they weren't chosen deliberately

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot +1 for the excelsior note! I didn’t even know this was there

Comment: Except Westview is in New Jersey, not New York - I guess she hasn't gotten new plates yet?  And the WANDA plate looks like Connecticut, even though the state name is replaced by Stan's birthday...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman That scene is before she creates the hex.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman There's no reason to believe the car needs to be registered in New Jersey. Wanda drove there because of the deed(?) she found on the passenger seat. The car is most likely a rental anyway. (She's only been back from the Blip for a few weeks and lived in a government compound prior to that; it's unlikely she owns her own car anyway.)

Comment: @chepner Isn't that government compound in the D.C. area though?  If anything I'd expect to see a Virginia or Maryland plate if it's a rental, but I guess they couldn't pass up that Excelsior motto on New York's...

Comment: As long as the drop-offs balance the pick-ups, I don't think there's any attempt to return one-way rentals to their original location. A car registered in one state could end up far from that state.

Comment: I only know [EXCELSIOR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wood_wool) as a material that was used before packing peanuts were invented.

Comment: It's very common to see New York plates in New Jersey and vice versa. Commuters, vacationers, family visits -- much of northern NJ is only an hour from New York City.

Comment: No need for a rental car's license plate to match the state, or even country, it's rented in. I once rented a car in Indiana that had an Ontario, Canada plate on it. (Speedo was also in KPH with a small MPH, instead of the US standard MPH with small KPH. Threw me for the first couple of miles...)